# How to set schema in db2batch query

Tags: db2, database-schema, batch-processing

How can I set schema before or in the statament of db2batch.

I am using below one.

```
db2batch -d ${DB_NAME} -a ${DB_USERNAME}/${DB_PASSWORD} -f ${input_file}
```

I have tried settting schema in the very first statement of input file. But its' not taking and throwing error.

Comment: Did you try to set the schema in the input file? set current schema

Comment: It's no taking. error.

Comment: It might be helpful to tell us the error message...

Comment: Yes, please provide the SQL statements in `${input_file}` and the error returned by `db2batch`